# What is a *generic vector* in contrast to a *dotted pair* list in the context of R and what does `alist()` do?

Tags: r, list

When reading the docs to `list()` I learned:

> Almost all lists in R internally are *Generic Vectors*, whereas
>   traditional *dotted pair* lists (as in LISP) remain available but rarely
>   seen by users (except as formals of functions).

I also read that `list()` generates a *generic vector* list, whereas `pairlist()` generates a *dotted pair* list.

However when looking at an example I see no difference: `list(x = 1, y = "a")` seems exactly the same as `pairlist(x = 1, y = "a")`.

Furthermore I'm intersted in what `alist()` generates. `alist` allows to give tags with no values (as in function formals): `alist(x, y)`. This is of course useful to define function formals and something that `list` and `pairlist` won't allow:

```
alist(x = , y = )
$x

$y
```

Now I'm intersted in what `alist()` produces:

- Is the output of `alist()` a *generic vector* or a *dotted pair*?
- Is the feature of allowing tags with no values a property of either *generic vector* or *dotted pair* lists?
- And what are the differences between *generic vector* lists and *dotted pair* lists in general?

Comment: [This](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) might be of interest. Excerpt: **alist() doesn’t evaluate its arguments so that alist(x = a) is shorthand for list(x = quote(a))**

Comment: See [The R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Pairlist-objects). Lists and pairlists differ [in their internal representation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html).

Comment: Thx @Roland and @NelsonGon, this helps. So if I see clear now, the feature of allowing `alist` to have *tags* with no *values* is specifically bound to *dotted pair* lists since R does not allow to define vectors with only *names* and no *values* (and therefore also no lists with only *tags* and no *values*)? Is this right? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Yes, `alist` is used for setting formals of a function and formals are implemented as a pairlist.